# Matching in awk

Tags: awk

What is wrong with this, please?

```
awk 'NR == FNR { x[$1]=$1; next} { print x[$5], $0 }' A.dat B.txt > C.txt
```

I would like:

If the first column of file A.dat is equal to the first column of file B.txt, then print the fifth column of file A.dat and the rest of file B.txt

A.dat

```
50551.4765 7.8001 7.8001 1.0000 7
50458.7628 7.3914 7.3914 1.0000 7
50134.5127 4.4601 4.4601 1.0000 4
50476.5679 7.2830 7.2830 1.0000 7
50102.5924 4.5385 4.4912 1.0105 4
```

B.dat

```
50102.5924   72.220    
50103.5903   -3.800   
50107.5850  -23.670    
50108.5331   40.380    
50108.7620   -7.620    
50109.5345   75.810   
50109.7681   54.510
```

Desired result
C.txt

```
4   50102.5924   72.220
```

Comment: Your question seems to have nothing to do with your subject line of `Setting encoding and terminal` - please fix your subject line to accurately summarize what your question is about so others searching the archives with a similar question in future can find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following code.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$NF;next} ($1 in arr){print arr[$1],$0}' A.dat B.dat
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '                ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{             ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE for A.dat
  arr[$1]=$NF        ##Creating arr with index of $1 and which has value of last field.
  next               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in arr){         ##Checking condition if 1st field is present in arr then do following.
  print arr[$1],$0   ##Printing arr with index of $1 and current line.
}
' A.dat B.dat        ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```